# Qt Creator: Segmentation Fault through SIGSEGV (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

After googling around I found out that segmentation faults are given when the program is pointed to use memory that it doesn’t have access to.

I’ve recently started experiencing these errors after I tried making a custom button class that would enclose, in its clicked() signal, an integer.

Here’s the custom button class:

#### .h:

```
#include <QtGui>

#ifndef CUSTOMBUTTON_H
#define CUSTOMBUTTON_H

class CustomButton : public QPushButton        //This simple class allows us to map arguments in the Widget's cicked() signal.
{                                              //In the project, it's used in the delete-edit buttons so the program knows which part of the Movie/Theater/Screening list we're referring to
 Q_OBJECT

public:
 CustomButton(QString name,int num, QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
 void clicked(int pos);

private:
 QSignalMapper *signalMapper;
};

#endif // CUSTOMBUTTON_H
```

#### .cpp:

```
#include "custombutton.h"

CustomButton::CustomButton(QString name,int num = 0, QWidget *parent) //Our constructor
    : QPushButton(name,parent)
{   //Our button's now created and shown, through the superconstructor. Let's take care of its clicked() signal.

    signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(this, num);


    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this, SIGNAL(clicked(int)));

}
```

And then in my main code I do:

```
CustomButton *edit_button = new CustomButton("Edit",i,0);
edit_button->setFixedWidth(30);
connect(edit_button,SIGNAL(clicked(int)),this,SLOT(edit_movie(int))); //When the user decides to edit a movie, we set the class'es working_with var to the position of the film in the MovieList and we set the screen to the appropriate one.


CustomButton *del_button = new CustomButton("Delete",i,0);            //We pass i as an argument to the button, so it can relate to the movie it's set next to.
del_button->setFixedWidth(45);
connect(del_button,SIGNAL(clicked(int)),this,SLOT(del_movie(int)));
```

Where i is the number I want it to have in the signal.

Thing is, thorugh the debugger it doesn’t give me a segfault if I press the Delete button. It all happens in the edit one.

As I’m still pretty confused and in a situation where I don’t even know WHAT to ask about, if you need anything else from me please say so and I will provide.

Here’s the backtrace, which I know not how to read:

```
0 QHash<QObject*, QString>::findNode qhash.h 884 0×69e98594
1 QHash<QObject*, QString>::contains qhash.h 874 0×69e98568
2 QSignalMapper::map qsignalmapper.cpp 267 0×69debe0c
3 QSignalMapper::map qsignalmapper.cpp 257 0×69debda2
4 QSignalMapper::qt_static_metacall moc_qsignalmapper.cpp 64 0×69debfce
5 QMetaObject::activate qobject.cpp 3547 0×69de9baf
6 QAbstractButton::clicked moc_qabstractbutton.cpp 220 0×10cb4b8
7 QAbstractButtonPrivate::emitClicked qabstractbutton.cpp 548 0xe2e517
8 QAbstractButtonPrivate::click qabstractbutton.cpp 541 0xe2e495
9 QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent qabstractbutton.cpp 1123 0xe2f941
10 QWidget::event qwidget.cpp 8362 0xae63de
11 QAbstractButton::event qabstractbutton.cpp 1082 0xe2f7cc
12 QPushButton::event qpushbutton.cpp 683 0xecfeba
13 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper qapplication.cpp 4554 0xa9c020
14 QApplication::notify qapplication.cpp 4097 0xa9a26a
15 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal qcoreapplication.cpp 876 0×69dd3b76
16 QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent qcoreapplication.h 234 0×113137e
17 QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent qapplication.cpp 3163 0xa98ad6
18 QETWidget::translateMouseEvent qapplication_win.cpp 3363 0xb03171
19 QtWndProc qapplication_win.cpp 1696 0xafdf66
20 USER32!IsDialogMessageW C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0 0×76726238
21 USER32!RegisterSystemThread C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0 0×767278b0
22 ?? 0 0×30000
23 USER32!AllowForegroundActivation C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0 0×767268ea
24 qt_is_translatable_mouse_event qapplication_win.cpp 1463 0xafd465
25 USER32!GetMessageExtraInfo C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0 0×76727d31
26 ?? 0
```

Any heads up as to what might be causing the problem? As I said, the segfault only occurs if I run the program through the Debugger and when I press the "Edit" button, of the CustomButton class. ***When I normally build&run, the program works 9/10 times. Sometimes, clicking the edit button results in a crash. This erratic behaviour is what caused me to look for help here.***

As when I click the button I'm taken to a new screen, I'm suspecting that the problem might lie in the decstructor? Does a blank destructor correctly deconstruct elements of objects of the CustomButton class, seeing as the actual object is passed to the base class constructor? Maybe I've got a leak there?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think we need more code since I can't see any mistake in your class. Please add more code where you use your class. Maybe it would be better to pass a parent pointer to your CustomButton instances. (I guess you create them within another widget.)

Comment: @Dimitris: The stack trace shows it's bailing out in QSignalMapper, I can't see anything wrong on first look, so can I ask why you've used it?

Comment: @leemes My whole project is quite big, and the last thing I want is alienating or tiring you guys by exposing you to big batches of my code. I've narrowed down the problem to be here. If by any means you'd like to see more, here's the whole thing. The situation where this happens is case 3 of the switch in showScreen(): http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Eygywtn1

Tried passing "this" as the parent, problem persists.

Thanks for the welcoming, also.

Comment: Actually I can see roughly the issue, the QSignalMapper is a useful tool in it's own context but I think it doesn't fit how you're trying to use it as you're creating multiple mappers, so rather than having one mapper for multiple buttons you're getting multiple mappers for one button.

Comment: @NicholasSmith why I've used the QSignalMapper?

I'm new to the whole signal&slot system, and after googling around and reading tutorials, it seemed that the only way to pass parameters with a signal (in my project passing a number with the clicked() signal of a button) was to map the value to a custom signal yourself, using the signalMapper object. Have I messed that up, somehow? Was there another way to do it?

Comment: What Nicholas tries to say is that you should put the signal mapper in the class where you use the buttons, not one for each button within the button itself. See my answer post for an alternative without signal mapper.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis: you can just use the signal slots without QSignalMapper and allow variables to be passed alongside them (bare examples: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). You can still use SignalMapper (and it'd probably achieve your goal if the buttons are fixed and don't change), look at the Qt example http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#details

Comment: I understand. I created signalMappers equal to the number of buttons, when I just needed ONE in the Game class. I understand where I went wrong, and the pointers of them probably caused the segfault somewhere.

Leeme's answer below solved it and gave me an approach that didn't even cross my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless knowing where you create the objects, it's hard to tell why there is a segfault in QSignalMapper. The pointer to your signal mapper might be invalid at some point in time, so there might be an unwanted deletion.

In some cases, a complete rebuild of your application might be helpful. Also re-running **qmake**. Just should be on your checklist when you can't explain why there is a segfault ...;)

There is an alternative to QSignalMapper: keep your signal clicked(int) and implement a private slot:

```
private slots:
    this_clicked() {
        emit clicked(num);
    }
```

Then put in the constructor:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(this_clicked()));
```

Comment: 11/10, 5 star reply, would get humbled by it again.

Your approach is much more intelligent and simplistic than mine and solved my problem. I thank you kindly and I shall have a beer in your name later tonight.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Don't forget to accept and maybe upvote my answer. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to accept the answer. There you go.